# Responsive Navigation Bar using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `twitter bootstrap 3` and trying to create a responsive navigation bar.

But the problem is when I re-size the window the width of the icons are getting to 100%.

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7fvt5/)

Someone help me in getting this fixed.

I want the width to the same when it's in the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right row">
    <li class="notifications-li dropdown col-xs-4">
    </li><!-- notifications -->

    <li class="tasks-li dropdown col-xs-4">
    </li><!-- tasks -->

    <li class="messages-li dropdown col-xs-4">
    </li><!-- messages -->
</ul>
```

Comment: that did help me in getting the li items to get arranged properly but when then i click on them. It doesn't look like arranged properly

Comment: oh sorry delete class - pull-right for "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" and will be working